# which javascript library convert application into RTL for arabia lang?

Tags: javascript

which javascript library convert application into RTL(right to left) for arabia lang??

i want to convert my application from ltr to rtl for arabia. is there any js library which can convert this??

Comment: Look at the "Quick Answer" here: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir .. is this what you're looking for?

Comment: thanks @J.Titus i am looking for pluggin or library which can convert complete aplication in to rtl right to left like arabia applications.